# how to check a radio button by clicking on a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

I am working on a data table which will be filled with Json data and I want to make the entire row clickable and when I click on the line, the radio button associated with it must be checked and return the value of the radio button

```js
var elements= document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++)
{

  (elements)[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  
   const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice"]');
            let selectedValue;
            for (const rb of rbs) {
                if (rb.checked) {
                    selectedValue = rb.value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            alert(selectedValue);
        
});
}
```

```css
tr:hover{
background-color:gray;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th></th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" value="Jhon doe" name="name"/></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="mary Moe" name="name" /></td>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="July dooley" name="name" /></td>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by just using the current `this` context like:

```
const rb = this.querySelector('input[name="choice"]');
rb.checked = true;
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

  (elements)[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const rb = this.querySelector('input[name="choice"]');
    rb.checked = true;

    let selectedValue = rb.value;
    alert(selectedValue);
  });
}
```

```css
tr:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="Jhon doe" name="choice" /></td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="mary Moe" name="choice" /></td>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="July dooley" name="choice" /></td>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this considerably using jQuery which you seem to already be including

```js
$('tr').click(function(e) { 
    $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', true); 
})
```

```css
tr:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="Jhon doe" name="name" /></td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="mary Moe" name="name" /></td>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="July dooley" name="name" /></td>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```